# BlackBerry Packager for Android Apps

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook

I'm trying to get my Android app ready for the BlackBerry by using this online packager: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/

So the first time I used it, it worked, but ever since I get unspecific errors during the signing process. ("Some error occured...")

Is it me or is it the packager? What is the easiest alternative to pack an Android app for the BlackBerry?

Comment: The only thing that might cause that is if you didn't set your build target for Android 2.3.3  For whatever reason this is one of the requirements for the Blackberry Packager.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the easiest alternative to pack an Android app for the BlackBerry?

I think you should try one of the other tools, because the online tool is not working for you and also because there are better ways.

I guess they created the online version to entice devs with a super simple option, but I don't think it is the best way to do it.  As well as the unhelpful error message that you got is the fact that it doesn't address testing...

As well as the online packager, they offer an Eclipse plug-in and a set of command-line tools:
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/tool

I used the Eclipse plug-in and I found it to be very simple and unobtrusive.  The support forum for the plug-in is here:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Plug-in-for-Android/bd-p/adt

The only thing that took me time was setting up the 'BAR signer', and I don't think there is any way around this.  To do that you need to follow the steps listed here:
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bar_signing_1904696_11.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't understand exactly what Eclipse is. Do I point with it to my .apk/.air file plus the BlackBerry signing key certificates and Eclipse creates a .bar file out of it? (My app is build with Adobe Air 2.5 - I can publish it as an .apk or .air file)

Comment: I can't comment on any differences between Air versus Java - I haven't used AIR.  Eclipse is a general purpose IDE and is the most common way to develop Java apps for Android or for Blackberry - perhaps it works with AIR as well?  In any event, if you aren't using Eclipse, you can do everything that I describe using command-line tools instead of Eclipse, BUT if you have an AIR app then maybe you should completely bypass the Android/APK tools and look for Playbook tools for AIR.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already packaged it and signed it, i believe it will throw an error if you try again, unless you change the version number to a higher value.

Comment: @Tom  If you havnt done so yet, i insist you try raising the version number in the apk. From my experience with developing adobe Air apps for playbook, it would throw an error if i tried to repackage the bar, without first raising the version number.

Comment: it explains why it worked the first time, but not again after that. I had the same issue way back when

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but I ran into similar problems and managed to get it working by using an older version of the SDK. The repackager tool doesn't work with the new v22 platform tools, so I had to downgrade my SDK to the older version before trying to run it through the online repackager.

You can manually download older versions of the SDK here:

http://www.hariadi.org/android/manually-download-of-android-sdk-tools-and-sdk-platform-tools/

Hope that helps.